# Adding empty view in place of RecyclerView below AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

I am having few issues in adding an custom empty view in place of recyclerview in layout. My custom empty view has gravity as "center_vertical". When I add it like this the image and text added in the custom empty view get hidden below the area in which the listview is displayed.It is getting out of the screen. I think that is happening because of "appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" for the SwipeRefreshLayout. But I do need to have that so that the appbar is scrolling as the list scrolls. But if no data is there to display I want the image in my custom empty view to be displayed below appbarlayout in center of the screen. Currently its getting pushed at the bottom of the screen.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
      android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/headRelativeLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

              <include
               android:id="@+id/topLayout"
               layout="@layout/top_sch_listview" />

              <include
                android:id="@+id/msgLayout"
                layout="@layout/view"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/topLayout" />

              <include
                android:id="@+id/subHeaderLayout"
                layout="@layout/view_sub_header"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/sub_header_height"
                android:layout_below="@+id/msgLayout" />

         </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
      android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

           <RelativeLayout
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

                   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                     android:id="@+id/recyclerListView"
                     android:layout_width="match_parent"
                     android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                     <com.my.views.CustomEmptyView
                      android:id="@+id/empty"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="match_parent" />
           </RelativeLayout>
   </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>

   <View
    android:id="@+id/blankView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Can someone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

CustomEmptyView's remove

recyclerListView
two ViewHoler's setting in adpater

emptyView holder > ( custom empty view )

DataView Holder > ( RecycleView : List )

```
public class AdvancedItemAdapter extends MultiItemAdapter {

public static final int VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY = 0;
public static final int VIEW_TYPE_DATA = 1;

@Override
public BaseViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    if (viewType == VIEW_TYPE_EMPTY) {
        EmptyViewHolder holder = (EmptyTYpeViewHolder)viewHolder;
        return holder;
    } else {
        DataViewHolder holder = (DataTYpeViewHolder)viewHolder;
        return holder;
    }

}
}
```

Data array count check

notifyDataSetChanged Previous

setType (tag ,  type value in viewholder class)

adapter notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I dont think that will work. It will behave the same way.